# driver is not used for Radeon HD 7770 ( running in Software Rendering Mode )

Tags: linux-mint, amd-graphics, radeon

I update my os to Mint 18.1 and I have an alert that said I'm running on software rendering mode when I boot. I'm trying to see which driver I'm using and I have this result.

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
       fabriquant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       ressources: mémoire:e0000000-efffffff mémoire:f7e00000-f7e3ffff portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:f7e40000-f7e5ffff
```

I think there is no driver used. I tried to install the open source driver for Radeon like this `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon` but nothing changed.

Is there something to do?

### Edit 1

Here is lsmod output :

```
Module                  Size  Used by
veth                   16384  0
xt_nat                 16384  5
xfrm_user              32768  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
br_netfilter           24576  0
aufs                  217088  215
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  2
iptable_mangle         16384  1
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  10
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 24576  3 nf_nat_ipv4,xt_nat,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  3
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           16384  2
nf_conntrack          106496  5 nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              16384  26
bridge                126976  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 stp,bridge
ebtable_filter         16384  0
ebtables               36864  1 ebtable_filter
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
x_tables               36864  13 ip6table_filter,xt_CHECKSUM,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack,xt_nat,iptable_filter,ebtables,ipt_REJECT,iptable_mangle,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype
binfmt_misc            20480  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
joydev                 20480  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
input_leds             16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
snd_usb_audio         176128  1
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hda_codec_via      24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_via
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_intel          40960  7
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_pcm               106496  6 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  28 snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei_me                 36864  0
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
ie31200_edac           16384  0
edac_core              53248  1 ie31200_edac
8250_fintek            16384  0
tpm_infineon           20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
hid_microsoft          16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  3 hid_generic,hid_microsoft,usbhid
psmouse               131072  0
pata_acpi              16384  0
atl1c                  49152  0
fjes                   28672  0
video                  40960  0
```

### Edit 2

Here is the output of `modinfo /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko` :

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    ATI Radeon
author:         Gareth Hughes, Keith Whitwell, others.
firmware:       radeon/R520_cp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RS600_cp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RS690_cp.bin
firmware:       radeon/R420_cp.bin
firmware:       radeon/R300_cp.bin
firmware:       radeon/R200_cp.bin
firmware:       radeon/R100_cp.bin
firmware:       radeon/SUMO2_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/SUMO2_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/SUMO_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/SUMO_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/SUMO_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/PALM_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/PALM_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/CYPRESS_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CYPRESS_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CYPRESS_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/CYPRESS_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/JUNIPER_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/JUNIPER_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/JUNIPER_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/JUNIPER_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/REDWOOD_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/REDWOOD_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/REDWOOD_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/REDWOOD_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/CEDAR_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CEDAR_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CEDAR_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/CEDAR_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/R700_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/R600_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV710_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV710_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV710_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV740_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV730_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV730_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV730_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV770_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV770_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV770_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RS780_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RS780_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV670_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV670_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV635_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV635_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV620_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV620_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV630_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV630_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV610_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV610_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/R600_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/R600_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/ARUBA_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/ARUBA_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/ARUBA_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAYMAN_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAYMAN_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAYMAN_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAYMAN_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAYMAN_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAICOS_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAICOS_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAICOS_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/CAICOS_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/TURKS_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/TURKS_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/TURKS_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/TURKS_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/BTC_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/BARTS_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/BARTS_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/BARTS_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/BARTS_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/hainan_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAINAN_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAINAN_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAINAN_mc2.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAINAN_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAINAN_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAINAN_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAINAN_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/oland_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/OLAND_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/OLAND_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/OLAND_mc2.bin
firmware:       radeon/OLAND_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/OLAND_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/OLAND_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/OLAND_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/verde_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/VERDE_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/VERDE_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/VERDE_mc2.bin
firmware:       radeon/VERDE_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/VERDE_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/VERDE_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/VERDE_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/pitcairn_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/PITCAIRN_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/PITCAIRN_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/PITCAIRN_mc2.bin
firmware:       radeon/PITCAIRN_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/PITCAIRN_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/PITCAIRN_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/PITCAIRN_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/tahiti_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_mc2.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/mullins_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/MULLINS_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/MULLINS_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/MULLINS_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/MULLINS_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/MULLINS_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/MULLINS_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/kabini_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/KABINI_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/KABINI_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/KABINI_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/KABINI_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/KABINI_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/KABINI_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_mec2.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/kaveri_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/KAVERI_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/KAVERI_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/KAVERI_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/KAVERI_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/KAVERI_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/KAVERI_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/hawaii_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_mc2.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/HAWAII_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/bonaire_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_smc.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_sdma.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_rlc.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_mc2.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_mc.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_mec.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_ce.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_me.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_pfp.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/SUMO_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/CYPRESS_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV710_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/RV770_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/RS780_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/R600_uvd.bin
firmware:       radeon/BONAIRE_vce.bin
firmware:       radeon/TAHITI_vce.bin
srcversion:     7AFED92ED8578E37C5FE65A
alias:          pci:v00001002d000099A4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
...
depends:        drm,drm_kms_helper,ttm,i2c-algo-bit
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-57-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           no_wb:Disable AGP writeback for scratch registers (int)
parm:           modeset:Disable/Enable modesetting (int)
parm:           dynclks:Disable/Enable dynamic clocks (int)
parm:           r4xx_atom:Enable ATOMBIOS modesetting for R4xx (int)
parm:           vramlimit:Restrict VRAM for testing, in megabytes (int)
parm:           agpmode:AGP Mode (-1 == PCI) (int)
parm:           gartsize:Size of PCIE/IGP gart to setup in megabytes (32, 64, etc., -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           benchmark:Run benchmark (int)
parm:           test:Run tests (int)
parm:           connector_table:Force connector table (int)
parm:           tv:TV enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           audio:Audio enable (-1 = auto, 0 = disable, 1 = enable) (int)
parm:           disp_priority:Display Priority (0 = auto, 1 = normal, 2 = high) (int)
parm:           hw_i2c:hw i2c engine enable (0 = disable) (int)
parm:           pcie_gen2:PCIE Gen2 mode (-1 = auto, 0 = disable, 1 = enable) (int)
parm:           msi:MSI support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           lockup_timeout:GPU lockup timeout in ms (default 10000 = 10 seconds, 0 = disable) (int)
parm:           fastfb:Direct FB access for IGP chips (0 = disable, 1 = enable) (int)
parm:           dpm:DPM support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           aspm:ASPM support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           runpm:PX runtime pm (1 = force enable, 0 = disable, -1 = PX only default) (int)
parm:           hard_reset:PCI config reset (1 = force enable, 0 = disable (default)) (int)
parm:           vm_size:VM address space size in gigabytes (default 4GB) (int)
parm:           vm_block_size:VM page table size in bits (default depending on vm_size) (int)
parm:           deep_color:Deep Color support (1 = enable, 0 = disable (default)) (int)
parm:           use_pflipirq:Pflip irqs for pageflip completion (0 = disable, 1 = as fallback, 2 = exclusive (default)) (int)
parm:           bapm:BAPM support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           backlight:backlight support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           auxch:Use native auxch experimental support (1 = enable, 0 = disable, -1 = auto) (int)
parm:           mst:DisplayPort MST experimental support (1 = enable, 0 = disable) (int)
```

Comment: Dougul, Show me using lsmod command  output. You should check Radeon HD 7770 loaded or not? When it was not a correct Radeon Driver.Linux mint wont load radeon driver but VGA vesa driver loaded.

Comment: @supriady I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see any Radeon driver loaded from your lsmod command output

I showed my lsmod output below here using Intel GM500 driver

# lsmod

gma500_gfx            192512  2

i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 gma500_gfx

drm_kms_helper        126976  1 gma500_gfx

Which kernel version did you use on linuxmint 18.1?

You can go to /lib/modules/kervel-versin/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/

You can do this command below here :

# modinfo radeon.ko

You should check on modinfo command output about your Radeon Driver.

When you can not find it.You should download Radeon HD 7770 driver from radeon website.

Comment: I added the output of the command. I'm using `4.4.0-57-generic`. The driver seems to exist.

Comment: Any radeon firmware matched with your radeon HD 7770 when you did modinfo command.When you can not find it.You should download it from Radeon Website.

Comment: I already downloaded it from http://support.amd.com/fr-fr/download but it doesn't work. X Server doesn't boot and I think there is a problem with the latest version. This is why I want to use open source driver. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333546/amd-radeon-driver-on-mint-18 for more information.

Comment: Maybe you can try to install kernel 4.9 using .deb package.Because kernel 4.9 deb package was available.I cant remember the website link.

Comment: I upgraded to kernel 4.9. I also install amdgpu-pro successfully as described here : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1215142#p1215142 but nothing changed.

Comment: The link was not about  Radeon HD 7770.When you did modinfo radeon.ko.You got Radeon R7xx firmware/driver on linux mint 18.1.You can try to run modprobe radeon.ko. I did some searches. I found Radeon HD 7770 driver from another website. Radeon HD 7770 driver size was 100+ MB.You can try to download it.